# iOS 5.0 Monotouch's NSUrl.ToString() method, possible bug

Tags: c#, ios, ios5, xamarin.ios

I've come across what I think is an interesting bug in iOS 5.0 (this code works perfectly in 5.1). After ages of narrowing it down using lots of Console.Write()'s, I narrowed the crash to:

```
nsUrl.ToString();
```

This is either in the MonoTouch library or iOS.

Anybody else come across this? It's annoying, as we obviously want to support the minimum iOS version possible.

Comment: objective c has no toString method, the closest thing is its description method for console logging.  What are you using this method for?  I think you should use the path property instead.

Comment: ps I am aware that this is c# code but I bet the toString method simply calls `description` which is not useful outside of logging.

Comment: Well it turned out that iOS (or MonoTouch) 5.0 must not support retrieving a UIWebView's Request from a LoadStarted event. You're exactly right Daniel, as the nsUrl was null because of this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MonoTouch the default `ToString` implementation, for `NSObject` subclasses, is to call the `description` selector.

In some cases (and yes it varies with iOS versions) calling `description` can fail (or even crash the process). That generally occurs when the native object is a bad state (e.g. mis-initialized, invalid value...).

MonoTouch tries to handle such cases (when possible and *known*) by using a different `ToString` implementation (e.g. with extra checks or by falling back to the default `ToString`, which returns the type name).

Note: If you find such behaviour please report them in [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com)s and we'll see if they can be handled differently.